# BigQuery - Joining and pivoting large tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I know there are some posts on pivoting, which I have used to get where I am today (thanks to the BQ community!).  But this post seeks some advice on optimising this where there is a large number of pivot columns needed, distributed table joins are needed....as well and deudping.  Not asking much right!

Objective:

We have 2 large BQ tables, with a full 10 years history that needs joining:

sales_order_header (13 GB - 1.35 million rows)
sales_order_line (50GM - 5 million rows)

This is a typical 'header/line' one to many relationship.  The data for the tables arrives as 2 seperate streams unfortunately rather then 1 document style where the line is nested inside the header which would be ideal - but its not so distributed joins become necesary for some of the views our BI tool (Tableau) wants to periodically (every 60 mins) call to ingest 'cleansed' data that is:

1. deduped (both tables that is)
2. joined header to line (on salesOrderId)
3. each has its own array of 'sourceData' namve / value paris that needs unpacking / 'pivot' so its not an array

Point 3 presents an issue in its own right.  We have a column called 'sourceData' which is basically where the core data is - its an array of string name value pairs (a row in BQ is a replication of a single row from a DB so the key is a column name and value the value for a single row).

Now I think here lay the issue, as there are 250 array entries (we know the exact number up front) , this equates to 250 'unnest' statements each and using the best approach I can think of using sub selects:

(SELECT val FROM UNNEST(sourceData) WHERE name = 'a') AS a,
250 times

And this is done as a pattern for each of the header and the line tables repsective views.

So the SQL for the view for just retrieving a deduped, flattened/pivoted array for the sales_order_header table is as follows.  The sales_order_line has the same pattern for its view:

```
#standardSQL
WITH latest_snapshot_dups AS (
  SELECT
    salesOrderId,
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez", lastUpdated) AS lastUpdatedTimestampUTC,
    sourceData,
    _PARTITIONTIME AS bqPartitionTime
  FROM 
    `project.ds.sales_order_header_refdata`
 ),
latest_snapshot_nodups AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY salesOrderId ORDER BY lastUpdatedTimestampUTC DESC) AS rowNum
  FROM latest_snapshot_dups
)
SELECT
  salesOrderId,
  lastUpdatedTimestampUTC,
  (SELECT val FROM UNNEST(sourceData) WHERE name = 'a') AS a,
  (SELECT val FROM UNNEST(sourceData) WHERE name = 'b') AS b,
  ....250 of these
FROM
  latest_snapshot_nodups
WHERE 
  rowNum = 1
```

Although just showing one here, we have these two similar views (with total of 250 + 300 = 550 unique subqueries that unnest/pivot), and now I want to join the header with the line views and I run into an issue straight away exceeding a limit of subqueries.

Is there a better way to do this, assuming this is the data there is to work with?  A better way to 'pivot' perhaps?  Or a more efficient way building a single view that optimises the order of things, rather then using 2 discrete views?

[image]

Thanks for your help BQ Community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I run into an issue straight away exceeding a limit of subqueries

You currently using below pattern (removed mot significant part of code for simplicity)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  salesOrderId,
  (SELECT val FROM UNNEST(sourceData) WHERE name = 'a') AS a,
  (SELECT val FROM UNNEST(sourceData) WHERE name = 'b') AS b,
  ....250 OF these
FROM latest_snapshot_nodups
```

Try below pattern

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  salesOrderId,
  MAX(IF(name = 'a', val, NULL)) AS a,
  MAX(IF(name = 'b', val, NULL)) AS b,
  ....250 OF these
FROM latest_snapshot_nodups, UNNEST(sourceData) kv
GROUP BY salesOrderId
```

Comment: awesome thanks Mikhail, will try this out much appreciated! One thing - I can see the use of a groupBy, I actually have about 10 other columns I would select in the projection as well not just salesOrderId used in the groupBy statement (e.g a number of dates and an external id).  Does having the groupBy limit this as an option?

Comment: you should just include all grouping columns into GROUP BY statement. For example, `GROUP BY salesOrderId, lastUpdatedTimestampUTC`